# how to iterate more number of times than size specified of list in java

Tags: java, list, iteration

I have a list of class type which holds value from object of class type in following way

```
public  List<Vacc_vs6> refarray_vac1(String fdate,String ldate) throws SQLException, ParseException {
    st_jsp.clear();
    try {  
        con = getConnection();
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        String vs1 = "sql query";
        stmt.executeQuery(vs1);
        rs = stmt.getResultSet();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Vacc_vs6 ref = new Vacc_vs6();

            ref.setLogtime(rs.getString(1));
            ref.setBeam_current(rs.getString(2));
            ref.setBeam_energy(rs.getString(3));
            ref.setst4_vs6_bag1_rb(rs.getString(4));
            ref.setst4_vs6_bag2_rb(rs.getString(5));
            ref.setst4_vs6_bag3_rb(rs.getString(6));
            ref.setst4_vs6_bag4_rb(rs.getString(7));
            ref.setst4_vs6_bag5_rb(rs.getString(8));
            ref.setst4_vs6_bag6_rb(rs.getString(9));
            ref.setst4_vs6_bag7_rb(rs.getString(10));
            ref.setst4_vs6_bag8_rb(rs.getString(11));
            ref.setst4_vs6_bag9_rb(rs.getString(12));
            st_jsp.add(ref);                  
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("\nException in refarray_vac1 " + e);
    }          
    return st_jsp;
}
```

st_jsp is the list.
Now I take another list of of class type and want to add values into it corresponding to every column of list st_jsp. I also want to add only those values in the second list which satisfy the given if condition otherwise go to else and put null at particular columns.
For this the code is-

```
List<Vacc_vs6> new_list=new ArrayList<Vacc_vs6>();
double is = 9.5;
double js = 10.5;
int no=0;
for (no=0;no<st_jsp.size();no++) {
    String i= st_jsp.get(no).getBeam_current();
    double im = Double.parseDouble(i) ;
    if(im>is && im<js) {
        new_list.addAll(st_jsp);
    } else  {
        new_list.addAll(null);
    }
    is +=10;js +=10; 
}
```

1. **Problem-1-->** how to add all the 12 columns corresponding to that index in `new_list.addAll(???)`; Did I have to add column where I put ??

   ref.setLogtime(rs.getString(1));
   ref.setBeam_current(rs.getString(2));
2. **Problem-2**  `for(no=0;no<st_jsp.size();no++)` loop will go till the size of `st_jsp` but if I do so then all values of `st_jsp` list will not be displayed because of else condition as I have to add `0` or `null` to those rows which do not satisfy the above if condition. What to do for this?

Answer (score 1):

> 1 Problem-1--> **how to add all the 12 columns corresponding to that index in new_list.addAll(???);**Did I have to add column where I put ??

To add only the object that satisfies your condition to the new list you should do:

```
if (im > is && im < js) {
    new_list.add(st_jsp.get(no));
}
```

The method `addAll()` adds all elements from one collection into another. So, the way you are doing it, the first time your condition is satisfied you are adding every ref in `st_jsp` to `new_list`. And then you will keep re-adding the elements everytime `new_list.addAll(st_jsp)` is called. Using `add()` will add only the object you want.

> 2) Problem-2 `for(no=0;no<st_jsp.size();no++)` loop will go till the size of `st_jsp` but if I do so then all values of `st_jsp` list will not be displayed because of else condition as I ahve to add `0` or `null` to those rows whcih do not satisfy the above if condition.What to do for this

You are doing the same action in `else` that you are doing when the `if` condition is satisfied, that is, adding all elements from `st_jsp` to `new_list`:

```
if (im > is && im < js) {
    new_list.addAll(st_jsp);
} else {
    new_list.addAll(st_jsp);
}
```

This means that, after your loop, you will end with `st_jsp.size()` copies of `st_jsp` in `new_list`.

If you need to add an object containing null in all fields to `new_list` everytime an object does not satisfy your condition you first need to create this object, and then add it when the condition is not met. Also, if you need to test for each element in `st_jsp` if it satisfies the conditions for all values of `is` and `js`, you need to place another loop inside the `for` loop.

```
List<Vacc_vs6> new_list = new ArrayList<Vacc_vs6>();
for (int no=0; no < st_jsp.size(); no++) {
    double is = 9.5;
    double js = 10.5;
    double im = Double.parseDouble(st_jsp.get(no).getBeam_current());
    // flag to check if an element was added to new_list
    boolean added = false;
    while (is < 209.9 && js < 210.5) {
        if (im > is && im < js) {
            new_list.add(st_jsp.get(no));
            added = true;
            break;
        }
        is += 10;
        js += 10;
    }
    if (!added) {
        // If the element was not added, add an empty object,
        // assuming that no field is set when creating the object.
        new_list.add(new Vacc_vs6());
    }
}
```

Comment: For problem 1 I did add   **new_list.add(st_jsp.get(no));**, but nothing is shown in output.Nothing is being added in new_list and even if condition is satisfied.                                                                                                                                        For problem 2 i did edit my code.How to resolve this issue of size()??

Comment: See if the code in my updated answer helps. From your question, you want to add an object with all fields null when a reference does not satisfy your condition.

Comment: This for loop will go till the st_jsp size.But I want that if the If condition is not satisfied and we go to else ,then the next iteration will be for next index if the value is not found then again else.ion this way the for llop will iterate till size of st_jsp. But through this I won't be able to compare all the values present in st_jsp as NULL will be added in new list if else comes.So what is the solution of it???

Comment: If you want to retest the same ref for different values of is and js, you need to have another loop inside the for loop, where you will increase the values for is and js. You also need a limit, so when is and js get to the limit you can stop the loop. What is the limit for is and js?

Comment: limit is 209.9 and 210.5

Comment: Updated the answer. Note that it will add an empty object to new_list every time the condition is not satisfied. I'm not sure that this is what you want.